Разница между update и save в библиотеке Sequelize?
Есть ли какая разница между двумя этими методами? update и save
// 1
const jane = await User.findOne({ {where: {name: 'Jane' }});
await jane.update({ favoriteColor: 'blue' });



// 2
const jane = await User.findOne({ {where: {name: 'Jane' }});
jane.favoriteColor = "blue"
await jane.save();


В случае save идёт 2 запроса. Селект и апдейт. В этот момент другой процесс может изменить объект.
В случае апдейт запрос только один и шансов испортить данные меньше.

В общем можно использовать update и забыть про save.

Save нужна когда нужно убедиться что другие поля соответствуют изменениям или при получении данных с внешних источников

Есть случаи когда save полезен, знать о том что он существует нужно.  Но у меня есть проект где даже не update, а только upsert
